# Getting all comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: posts and comments. Each comment belongs to a post. I would like to have a page of all comments not just the comments for a post.  I can't seem to get this seemingly simple thing to work.

Here is my controller:

```
def top
  @topcomments = @comments.order("created_at desc")
end
```

I am getting an 'undefined method order' error.

Comment: Thats all i have. Not sure what to make @comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access comments directly, and not through a relationship with another model, you need to access the model itself, `Comment`:

```
def top
  @topcomments = Comment.order('created_at desc')
end
```

---

> how would you get the post for each comment

Assuming you have a relationship set up correctly between comments and posts, you would just access `.post` for each comment. You can use `includes(:post)` to avoid the [n+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

```
def top
  @topcomments = Comment.order('created_at desc').includes(:post)

  @topcomments.each |comment|
    comment.post # here is the post
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. Quick question: how would you get the post for each comment. For each comment i am doing a 'link_to (@post.title)' but it is an undefined post.

Comment: @user2759575 See update; too much to fit in a comment.

Comment: OK so comment.post gets the post but then comment.post.title gets 'undefined method title'. It looks like this: @topcomments.each do |comment] link_to (comment.post.title) end

Answer (score 1):

```
def top
    @topcomments = Comment.order("created_at desc")
end
```